# MsgBox within an If statement not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the following code to open a password protected file if the Windows user is "bhope" or "jdean" and display a message box if the user is anyone else. It opens the file as needed when the user is "bhope" or "jdean" but if another user clicks the button, nothing happens/no error. What am I missing?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strUser As String
strUser = Environ("USERNAME")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Select Case strUser

    ' Full Workbook Access
    Case Is = "bhope", "jdean"
       If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then _
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="M:\...", Password:="TEST")

    ' Limit Access
    Case Is = "mjackson" 'also tried "Case Is <> "bhope", "jdean"
       If Not ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then _
          MsgBox ("This button is reserved for SAMs")
  End Select

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If it helps, I used [this link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/80796-how-set-readonly-vba.html) to start the base of the code and tried to modify it from there. Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Are you sure the userid of the other user is `"mjackson"`, and not perhaps `"MJackson"`?

Comment: Change `Select Case strUser` to `Select Case LCase(strUser)`

Comment: FWIW - The simplest thing to cater for "anyone else" is to use `Case Else` for the second case.

Comment: @YowE3K I wasn't aware the user name could be case sensitive. Unfortunately though, all user names are lower case.

Comment: @JohnyL I tried your suggestion and nothing happens still. For my knowledge, your solution would have made all usernames lower case, yes?

Comment: No, not all usernames are lowercase.  Mine isn't.

Comment: @YowE3K I replaced my Case Is = "mjackson" with your case else option but I still have nothing happen when the case else should be firing the message box. I tried your suggestion with and without johnyl's suggestion.

Comment: Why are you turning off `Application.ScreenUpdating`?  Are you under the impression that's a security option?  Why are you checking if the workbook is opened as `Read Only`?  Are you sure it _is_ Read Only?  You do realize that there are very simple ways around "security" like this?

Comment: You shouldn't guess which case a user's account can be - that's why you convert all characters into lower case. Thus, you can safely make a comparison.

Comment: Did you try his other suggestion too?  You have more than one thing that could be going wrong, so the next step of  troubleshooting is to start removing lines until your message box is working, and then add your code back in one thing at a time until you find the problem.  Please check out: [mcve]

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  Can you explain step by step?  Maybe some screen shots?  Also, if you're not logged in as the user who's "security" you're setting up, there's not much point in trying to troubleshoot why "his" msgbox isn't opening.

Comment: It seems strange that you are opening a file when two specific users run the macro from a read-only workbook, but you want to give a message to other users only if the macro is run from a **non** read-only workbook.  You have four scenarios - (1) valid users from read-only workbook (2) valid users from non read-only (3) invalid users from read-only (4) invalid users from non read-only.  What do you want to do in each of those four situations?

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `IS` here may be the culprit. At best it's superfluous, at worse it's masking this issue. Instead try:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strUser As String
strUser = Environ("USERNAME")

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Select Case strUser

    ' Full Workbook Access
    Case "bhope", "jdean"
       If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then _
          Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="M:\...", Password:="TEST")

    ' Limit Access
    Case "mjackson" 
       If Not ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then _
          MsgBox ("This button is reserved for SAMs")
  End Select

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Also consider changing that second CASE to `CASE ELSE`.

The other thing is that your msgbox is inside of your `IF` condition. `strUser` must be uqual to `mjackson` AND the ActiveWorkbook (whatever that might be at the time this code executes) must NOT be ReadOnly for that msgbox to fire.

1. Consider changing "ActiveWorkbook" to be more specific. Perhaps `ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly`?
2. Consider an `Else` for your if statement to see if the `mjackson` is hitting but the `readonly` is not:

   ```
   Case "mjackson" 
      If Not ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then 
         MsgBox ("This button is reserved for SAMs")
      Else
         MsgBox ("ActiveWorkbook is not Read Only so yo get this message")
      End If
   ```

Lastly, put a breakpoint (F9) on `SELECT` and see what your value of `strUser` as while the code is running (hover over `strUSer` on that line or check your Locals pane). You may also want to see what `ActiveWorkbook` is at this point of time too, just in case. The answer will, again, be in your Locals pane, so make sure that is turned on in the `view` drop down of VBE.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. Apparently the "case else" I said I tried earlier was actually done to another test file with similar code as I usually have several open when I'm testing to compare behaviors. I also had to delete the line below "case else" so that only the msg box line would run after that. Below is the code I used should anyone need it in the future:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strUser As String
strUser = Environ("USERNAME")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Select Case LCase(strUser)
' Full Workbook Access
Case Is = "bhope", "jdean"
If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly Then _
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="M:...", Password:="TEST")
' Limit Access
Case Else
MsgBox ("This button is reserved for SAMs")
End Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To answer earlier questions: my understanding of screen update is that if it's turned off, the application will run non-visually so as not to cause concern for the users who will be using this file. Also, this code makes it run faster, does it not?

As far as the purpose of the workbook and security concerns... the button will be used on a read only workbook that houses many portions of our company's metrics. The file is made read only so that users cannot save over it. Since the file is kind of big and a lot of data is expected to go into it, my thought process was to load the "Shell" of the main file then have buttons that determine who should be allowed to add info to certain sheets. By having both files read only and password-protected, I'm able to open the 2nd sheet when the appropriate user clicks the button, then have data transfer back and forth between the workbooks. I still intend on password protecting the VBA code so I don't see how their could be a security concern. Also, @ashleedog, I meant that everyone in our company has lower case user names.